# How to filter the grid data(Ng-grid) on the basis of selection date range via AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-filters

Actually I have a combo box with values "Last seven days", "Last three days" and "Today", I want to apply the filter on the basis of selected value date range by current date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the solution for filtering the data of the grid view on the basis of selected Date options from the combo box as described in the problem statement:

Here durationFilter() is the function call on the change of the value in the combo box

```
$scope.durationFilter = function () {
            var currentDate = new Date();
            var difDate = new Date();
            $scope.filteredItems = [];

            switch ($scope.selectedItem.id) {
                case 1:
                    $scope.range = 1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $scope.range = 3;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $scope.range = 7;
                    break;
                default:
                    $scope.range = 0;
                    $scope.filteredItems = [{ 0: new Date() }];
                    $scope.gridOptions.filterOptions.filterText = '';
                    break;
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.range; i++) {
                currentDate.subtractDays(i);
                difDate = currentDate;
                $scope.difDate = $filter('date')(difDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy');
                $scope.filteredItems.push($scope.difDate);
                currentDate = new Date();
            }
            $scope.searchingFilters.filteredDate = $scope.filteredItems;
            $scope.setFilterText();
        };

        $scope.setFilterText = function () {
            $scope.gridOptions.filterOptions.filterText = 'Submit Time:' + $scope.searchingFilters.filteredDate[0] + '|' + $scope.searchingFilters.filteredDate[1] + '|' +
                                                                     $scope.searchingFilters.filteredDate[2] + '|' + $scope.searchingFilters.filteredDate[3] + '|' + $scope.searchingFilters.filteredDate[4] +
                                                                     '|' + $scope.searchingFilters.filteredDate[5] + '|' + $scope.searchingFilters.filteredDate[6] + ';';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the filterOptions of the grid are not working for you then try keeping your full set of data in one array and the filtered set in another. Set the gridOptions.data to your filtered set. Apply a function when the user makes a selection from the dropdown that sets your filtered set to whatever you want.  Something like this:

```
  <select ng-model="filterValue"><option value=1>Last 7 days</option></select>

  $scope.allItems = [{someDate:'10/21/14'},{someDate:'11/2/14'},{someDate:'10/24/14'}];
  $scope.filteredItems = [];
  $scope.filterValue;
  $scope.$watch("filterValue", function() {
     // filter your dataset here
     if($scope.filterValue == 1) {   // Last 7 days
         angular.forEach(allItems,function(value) {
             // Use something like moment.js to do date arithmetic
             if(date in last 7 days) {
                   $scope.filteredItems.push(value);
             }
         });
     }

  };

  $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'filteredItems' ....};
```

Comment: The grid filters are working, however i am unable to figure out how to apply filter on the basis of selected duration value from the drop down. For Example if the user selects last 7 days then the grid view should be filtered and should show data of last seven days. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer above to give a bit more detail as I'm still not sure where your having a problem. Note that you'll need to use a library like moment.js to do the Date arithmetic to figure out which dates to include.

Comment: Thanks Scott! As I had a limitation to use any libraries, I am working on this and will come up with the answer